# Jquery, get label value inside a user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I need to make a calculation in an asp.net page with the value from a usercontrol label.

the user control label is:

```
 <asp:Label ID="LblInvoicePriceValue" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

I include it like this:

```
<Controls:VehicleInformation ID="VehicleInformationControl" runat="server" />
```

And my jquery function is something like:
Please see point 1 and 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('call function to do calculation here');
            // 1.   Find in the vehicle information user control the invoiced ammount label
            // 2.   Find the vat excluded value **after** it was typed in the textbox
            // 3.   If invoiced ammount is greater than zero, then
            // 3.a  Find Label Percentage 
            // 3.b  Label.Text = (AmmountWithoutVat/InvoicedAmmount)*100 + '%'
        });
  </script>
```

**HTML generated:UPdate1**

For the label:

```
 <span id="MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue" class="bold"></span>
```

For the textbox:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TxtVatExcluded" type="text" id="TxtVatExcluded" class="calculation" />
```

**Update 2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('call function to do calculation here');

            $("#TxtVatExcluded").keypress(function() {
                var invoiceprice = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
                var vatexcluced = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
                var lblPercentage = $("#MainContent_LblPercentage");
                if (invoiceprice > 0) {
                    lblPercentage.text((vatexcluced / invoiceprice) * 100);
                }
            })

            // 1.   Find in the vehicle information user control the invoiced ammount label
            // 2.   Find the vat excluded value after it was typed in the textbox
            // 3.   If invoiced ammount is greater than zero, then
            // 3.a  Find Label Percentage 
            // 3.b  Label.Text = (AmmountWithoutVat/InvoicedAmmount)*100 + '%'
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: can you include the actuall HTML output (using view source would be sufficient) that the controls / label produces ...

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard if you've read up on jQuery for about an hour or two. $("#theID").val() will get you the value of that id and $("#theID").blur( function () {}) will let you define what happens when the focus leave that field (assuming theID is an input element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var label_text = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
$("#TxtVatExcluded").val(label_text);
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to check if the textfield is blank then only do copy the label then use following code

```
var label_text = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
var txt = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
if(txt.length==0)
{
  $("#TxtVatExcluded").val(label_text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rendered ID of the elements to get the values using jQuery

```
var lbl = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
var tbox = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
```

Later when the calculation is complet, you can update the label text as

```
$("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").html("new label");
```

#### Update:

To use the logic, where the user types, you have to bind the function to `keypress`/`keyup`/`keydown` event

```
$("#myinputbox").keypress(function() {
    var lbl = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
    var tbox = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
    //... so on
}
```

#### Update 2:

Since, you are attempting to calculate with the values, it is safer to make sure, there are numbers in the first place. For that, you can use `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()` as needed.

```
        $("#TxtVatExcluded").keypress(function() {
            var invoiceprice = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
            var vatexcluced = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
            var lblPercentage = $("#MainContent_LblPercentage");
            if (invoiceprice > 0) {
                lblPercentage.text((parseInt(vatexcluced) / parseInt(invoiceprice)) * 100);
            }
        })
```

Comment: and how to make my logic execute only after the user has typed something into the textbox

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the value of the label control:

```
function Calculate()
{
    var InvoicedAmmount = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
    var AmmountWithoutVat = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();

    var Result = (AmmountWithoutVat/InvoicedAmmount)*100

    $("#OutputLabel").html(Result + " %");
}
```

You can attach and onBlur event to your text box to fire your calculation when they leave the text box - you wouldn't really want to re-calculate the amount as they typed.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    $("#TxtVatExcluded").bind("blur",function(){ Calculate(); });
}
```